# Ruby on rails - rake db:schema:dump, cannot find the path specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, schema, dump

I'd like to dump schema of my MySql database but when i try to do it than i have error:

> C:\Users\p\Sites\simple_cms>rake db:schema:dump
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

It's my very first time with Ruby/Ruby on rails and I perform everything according "Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training". Now i don't have any idea where i can find any solution of this problem.

Here is my Gemfile.lock:

```
... rake (>= 0.8.7)
  thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
rake (12.0.0)...
```

I can show you everything in this file if you want but its 170 lines so maybe it will be enough.

Here is my database.yml:

```
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
username: dev_user
password: password
host: localhost
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: How about other rake tasks like migrate or rollback?

Comment: All of rake's command does not work. I tried in project's bin folder and also in .../RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\bin

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved the problem after reinstalling 'rake'.